# exception in NSArrayM insertObject:atindex

Tags: ios, nsarray

i have used 4 images in project ..while running it results in:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
>   *** First throw call stack:

my code :

```
NSArray *imageNames= @[@"jake_2.png",@"jake_3.png",@"jake_4.png",@"jake_5.png "];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++)
{
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
    UIImageView *slowAnimationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 95, 86, 193)];
    slowAnimationImageView.animationImages = images;
    slowAnimationImageView.animationDuration = 5;
    [self.view addSubview:slowAnimationImageView];
    [slowAnimationImageView startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: put a code in code Brackets , its difficult to understand your code now

Comment: read the error message `object cannot be nil`

Comment: Check your images Names once. Images you are storing should not be nil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're facing issue because the imageName you provided in array is not available in the resources. Check the last object in array :  **@"jake_5.png "**. There's an extra space in it. Please remove it. Thats what causing this issue.

UPDATE :

For animation, you need to set it after all images are added in your imageArray. Refer this code for help and make changes :

```
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++)
{
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
}

slowAnimationImageView.animationImages = images;
slowAnimationImageView.animationDuration = 5;
[slowAnimationImageView startAnimating];
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: i need to use a button with animation.help me out in that

Comment: yeahh i need to animate

Answer (score 1):

There is little mistake with the Space with name of the last image

```
 NSArray *imageNames= @[@"jake_2.png",@"jake_3.png",@"jake_4.png",@"jake_5.png"];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for image in imagesNames
    {
        [images addObject:[image];
        UIImageView *slowAnimationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 95, 86, 193)];
        slowAnimationImageView.animationImages = images;
        slowAnimationImageView.animationDuration = 5;
        [self.view addSubview:slowAnimationImageView];
        [slowAnimationImageView startAnimating];
    }
```

but if you don't want to add the for loop like this use the method **addObjectOfArray** to append the object in the Mutable Array

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because there is one extra space in `@"jake_5.png "`:

```
NSArray *imageNames= @[@"jake_2.png",@"jake_3.png",@"jake_4.png",@"jake_5.png "];
```

as it should be:

`@"jake_5.png"`

***Addendum:***

The way you want `UIImageView` to animate a series of images is not correct:

Please replace yours with the following:

```
UIImageView *slowAnimationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 95, 86, 193)];
[self.view addSubview:slowAnimationImageView];

NSArray *imageNames = @[@"jake_2.png", @"jake_3.png", @"jake_4.png", @"jake_5.png"];

NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++)
{
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
}

slowAnimationImageView.animationImages = images;
slowAnimationImageView.animationDuration = 5;
[slowAnimationImageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: No, you do not use `nil` at the end when using the `@[ ]` syntax.

Comment: @rmaddy But my "side note" also mentions the space, which causes error. It also goes to show that the way he is trying to animate the images is wrong. The way he is trying to animate would have no animation of images whatsoever, because the property `animationImages` will hold just one single image in the end of loop.

Comment: Fix all your references to using `nil` at the end of the array and then you will have a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *imageNames= @[@"jake_2.png",@"jake_3.png",@"jake_4.png",@"jake_5.png "]; replace it with 
NSArray *imageNames= @[@"jake_2.png",@"jake_3.png",@"jake_4.png",@"jake_5.png"];
```

because you put the space @"jake_5.png " may be this image was not available in resource so it give you error.

Comment: No, you do not use `nil` at the end when using the `@[ ]` syntax.

Comment: if nil is used it gives an error as:collection element of type void is not an objective c object

Comment: can you check image names in resources ?
what is the image name of "jake_5.png" or "jake_5.png "
you also check it through your loop make loop like  for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count-1; i++)  if its works then definitely issue in your last name of image.

Comment: i need to use a button with animation.help me out in that